Triggering an Azure DevOps pipeline from another pipeline that is triggered by a tag push
Base on this article Triggering an Azure Devops pipeline from another pipeline, I'm attempting to configure the dependent pipeline to run only when the source pipeline is triggered by a tag push. Below are the configurations for both pipelines:
source pipeline
trigger:
  branches:
    include: # branch names which will trigger a build
    - main
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'
pr: none

steps:
  # required to cause pipeline triggering downstream
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.yml
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifactName: dummy-$(Build.BuildId)

depends pipeline
trigger: none

pr: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - main
        tags:
        - '*'

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: echo 'triggered depends'

The result is the depends pipeline not triggered.
I attempted to adjust the tag trigger configuration for the dependent pipeline, aiming to specify a particular tag instead of using a wildcard character '*' as per the documentation on Azure Pipelines YAML schema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource.
However, I'm uncertain whether Azure Pipelines supports triggering a pipeline solely based on tags after another pipeline is triggered, or if tags are primarily used for filtering trigger events.
Moreover, i want to trigger the pipeline source pipeline from another repo, the yaml for source repo in this case as follows
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: demoRepo
    type: git
    name: Project/demoRepo
    trigger:
      tags:
        include:
          - '*'
pr: none

...

Based on the YAML configuration above, I expect that when I push a tag on demoRepo, both the source pipeline and the depends pipeline will run consecutively. However, I encountered an issue where the source pipeline runs, but the depends pipeline does not trigger.

As far as I understand, the requirement was to trigger source pipeline with the commits in the tags of your repo and upon the completion of the source pipeline, the depends pipeline should be triggered.
Based on your YAML definitions, I could reproduce the issue. This was because the tags property of a pipeline resource was designed to filter source pipeline builds with specific build tags rather than the tagged code in our repo.
For a further test to meet your requirement, I managed to trigger the downstream pipeline with branch includes refs/tags/*. Here is the sample for your reference.
source pipeline
trigger:
  branches:
    include: # branch names which will trigger a build
    - main
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'
pr: none

steps:
  - script: echo This is source pipeline
  - script: |
      echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]ABuildTag"
    displayName: Add a tag for the build of source pipeline

  # It is not required to publish any artifacts to trigger depends pipeline; the depends pipeline should be triggered upon the completion of the source pipeline
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.yml
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifactName: dummy-$(Build.BuildId)

depends pipeline
trigger: none

pr: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining 
      source: source
      # tags:
      # - ABuildTag
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - refs/heads/main
          - refs/tags/*
        tags:
        - ABuildTag

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: |
      echo $(resources.pipeline.source.runName)
      echo $(resources.pipeline.source.runID)
      echo $(resources.pipeline.source.sourceBranch)
  - download: source



This is super useful thanks,  I have one more question. I'm trying to trigger a pipeline in across repository resources.repositories https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories?view=azure-pipelines based on a tag push. However, the "depends" pipeline does not trigger after the "source" pipeline.

FYI, I added the detail of pipeline yaml on my post.

Hi @MR.Nate, Glab to know the answer helps. Would you please create a new thread for us to trach the repo resource trigger issue? Thx for the efforts.

You can find the new thread as this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78487477/triggering-an-azure-devops-pipeline-from-another-pipeline-that-is-triggered-by-a

If I'm not mistaken, wildcards such as * can be used to filter branches but not tags.
So, instead of:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - main
        tags:
        - '*'

Try:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - main
        tags:
        - mytag

Please note that if you include more than one tag, the build will be triggered only when ALL the tags are added to the source pipeline.
