Triggering an Azure DevOps pipeline from another pipeline that is triggered by a tag push from another repo
Base on previous thread I posted about triggering pipeline from another pipeline by tag push Triggering an Azure DevOps pipeline from another pipeline that is triggered by a tag push is solved now but it's coming with new problem when I'm trying to trigger another pipeline from different repository as detail below.
Source pipeline
pr: none
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: demoRepo
    type: git
    name: Project/demoRepo
    trigger:
      tags:
        include:
          - '*'

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]ABuildTag"
      displayName: Add a tag for the build of source pipeline
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.yml
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifactName: dummy-$(Build.BuildId)

Depends pipeline
trigger: none
pr: none
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - refs/tags/*
        tags:
        - ABuildTag

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: echo 'triggered depends'


According to the pipelines yaml above, depends pipeline did not execute after source pipeline as it should have when I triggered the source pipeline from another repo (demoRepo).

In Figure 1 above, the UI shows that the source pipeline is triggered on the main branch. However, I pushed a tag and set the trigger to be refs/tags/* as mentioned earlier.
But when I click into the source pipeline. it's show me the detail of each run which is trigger by tag I pushed as fig below.


As suggested in my answer below, you can try to remove the branches filter and only use the build tags filter on the Depends pipeline. Or change the branches filter to '- refs/heads/main'. @MR.Nate

There are some points you need to know:

In a pipeline, if the defined resource trigger is from another repository, the current pipeline will be always triggered on (run on) the default branch of the self repository that the current pipeline is in. That's why your Source pipeline is triggered on the main branch that is the default branch of the self repository not the demoRepo repository.

In the Depends pipeline, it is directly triggered by the Source pipeline not the demoRepo repository, so, the filters set on the pipeline resource will just evaluate the repository where the Source pipeline is in.

The filter '- refs/tags/*' you defined on the pipeline resource is to detect the tags from the repository where the Source pipeline is in, not the demoRepo repository.

Similar, the tag '- ABuildTag' also should be the build tags added on the Source pipeline. It is not the git tags. You can add the build tags to a build either by manual or using the 'addbuildtag' command during running the current build.






For your case, you can try to change the configurations like as below:

In the the Source pipeline, add run the 'addbuildtag' command to create a build tag (for example, resRepoTagTriggered).

. . .

steps:
- bash: echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]resRepoTagTriggered"
  displayName: 'Add Build Tag'


In the Depends pipeline, change to any of the following configurations.

Remove the branches filter.



resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger:
        tags:
        - resRepoTagTriggered


Change the branches filter to '- refs/heads/main'.

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: source
      # project: Pipelining
      source: source
      trigger: 
        branches:
          include:
          - refs/heads/main
        tags:
        - resRepoTagTriggered


